# Splitting a list into two using Python?

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn to program and I received the following problem for homework utilizing Python. I was wondering if anyone can help explain what I need to do to

Implement function partition() that splits a list of soccer players into two groups. More precisely, it takes a list of first names (strings) as input and prints the names of those soccer players whose first name starts with a letter between and including A and M.

```
partition([‘Eleanor’, ‘Evelyn’, ‘Sammy’, ‘Owen’, ‘Gavin’])
```

outputs:

```
Eleanor

Evelyn

Gavin
```

and

```
partition([‘Xena’, ‘Sammy’, ‘Owen’])
```

doesn't print anything.

Comment: What have you got so far? What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the exact problem definition you might be looking for something like:

```
def partition(l):
    return [firstname for firstname in l
            if firstname[0].lower() in 'abcdefghijklm']

def partition2(l):
    return [firstname for firstname in l
            if 'a' <= ord(firstname[0].lower())
               and ord(firstname[0].lower()) <= 'm']
```

Note that these strictly match only the ASCII chars between 'A' and 'M'.

Comment: I would pass `abcdefghijklm` as a parameter to partition.

Comment: Well, yeah. And what about the index and the phase of the moon?

Comment: Huh? The comment was more towards the individual who posted the question. They mentioned they were just starting out so it might not be so obvious to them. I can easily see two functions now called partitionAtoM() and partitionNtoZ() when a single function would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would not user partition in this case.
Try the following:

```
import re
players = ['Eleanor', 'Evelyn', 'Sammy', 'Owen', 'Gavin']
am_players = filter(lambda p: re.match('^[A-M].*',p,re.I), players)
nz_players = filter(lambda p: re.match('^[N-Z].*',p,re.I), players)
```

Comment: I think this is the way I would go, but since the poster mentioned they were only just beginning programming I think introducing lamda and regular expressions might be too much.

Answer (score 0):

If your partition function prints only the names that starts with letter since 'A' to 'M' then `partition(['Xena', 'Sammy', 'Owen'])` will not print anything.

And that's the reason cause your output is empty.